# Data loss without downtime with Redis

Tags: redis

Redis seems to have lost some of my data, without the server process dying. The first new data to have persisted seems to be at 12:26. Logs from Redis are below. redis-cli info stats show the process uptime is 3 days. Is this RDB background saving failing? There is ample disk space available.

The Redis version is 4.0.6

```
24121:M 16 Dec 12:17:26.011 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
24121:M 16 Dec 12:17:26.117 * Background saving started by pid 370
370:C 16 Dec 12:17:44.994 * DB saved on disk
370:C 16 Dec 12:17:45.068 * RDB: 167 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
24121:M 16 Dec 12:17:45.260 * Background saving terminated with success
24121:M 16 Dec 12:21:19.891 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:21:21.465 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:00.152 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:00.474 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:32.699 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:33.044 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:33.579 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:33.993 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:34.462 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:35.167 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:35.500 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:22:36.107 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:02.170 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:02.564 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:02.853 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:03.142 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:03.505 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:03.792 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:04.174 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:04.526 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:04.898 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:05.214 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:05.573 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:06.078 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:06.266 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:06.452 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:19.422 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:29.048 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:38.699 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:48.633 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:23:58.422 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:24:08.165 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:24:18.620 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:24:28.847 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:24:38.802 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:24:48.660 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:24:58.978 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:25:11.011 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:25:21.948 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:25:32.383 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:25:43.789 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:25:58.678 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:26:10.804 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:26:21.522 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:26:32.147 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:26:42.517 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:26:52.922 * DB saved on disk
24121:M 16 Dec 12:31:53.081 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
24121:M 16 Dec 12:31:53.092 * Background saving started by pid 8671
8671:C 16 Dec 12:31:54.833 * DB saved on disk
8671:C 16 Dec 12:31:54.839 * RDB: 12 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
24121:M 16 Dec 12:31:54.898 * Background saving terminated with success
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (Which is somewhat centred about "programming" - server-side DB questions may fare better over at [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).) `Redis seems to have lost some of my data…` please present what made that impression.

Comment: If you run `redis-server` sometimes your will see configuration warnings.  If memory serves, one of the warning relates to background saving.  You may want to run the server from the command line and inspect the warnings.

Comment: Keys with extremely long TTLs (multiple days) suddenly disappeared as a group. Memory usage of redis drastically dropped.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this [FAQ](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/b6354d92a2d51c141490f10142884ea4) provides an answer to your question:

> Redis doesn't really lose keys randomly. If the keys have disappeared,
>   then it is likely because of one of the following reasons:
>
> Expiration: The TTL specified on a key was hit, so the system removed
>   the key. More details around Redis expiration can be found in the
>   documentation for the Expires command. TTL values can be set through
>   operations like SET, PSETEX or EXPIRE.
>
> The INFO command can be used to get stats about how many keys have
>   expired using the expired_keys entry under the STATS section. You can
>   also see the number of keys with a TTL value, as well as the average
>   TTL value, in the KEYSPACE section.
>
> ```
> # Stats
> expired_keys:46583
>
> # Keyspace 
> db0:keys=3450,expires=2,avg_ttl=91861015336    
> See related article with debugging tips
> ```
>
> Eviction:
>   **Under memory pressure, the system will evict keys to free up memory**. When the used_memory or used_memory_rss values in the INFO
>   command approach the configured `maxmemory` setting, the system will
>   start evicting keys from memory based on your configured memory policy
>   as described here. You can monitor the number of keys evicted using
>   the same INFO command mentioned previously
>
> ```
> # Stats
> evicted_keys:13224
> ```